# Copy an element from one array to another in PowerShell

Tags: arrays, powershell

I am trying to copy an element from one multi-dimensional array to another multi-dimensional array(the elements of each array are as an example):

(array1)

```
EmpID        Badge        WorkEmail
1234         ABCD         john@acme.com
2345         JKLM         mary@acme.com
4567         QWER         paul@acme.com
```

(array2)

```
EmpName        UserID        Email
John           1234          john@acme.com
Mary           JKLM          mary@acme.com
Linda          POIU          linda@acme.com
Paul           QWER          paul@acme.com
```

I have created an alias for the element **Email** in *array2* called **WorkEmail**:

```
$array2 = $array2 | Add-Member -MemberType AliasProperty -Name WorkEmail -Value "Email" -PassThru
```

I am using *Compare-Object* to compare these two arrays based upon the **WorkEmail** element / alias and I want to keep all objects from *array1* when **WorkEmail** is equal in both *array1* and *array2*:

```
$arrayNew = @(Compare-Object $array1 $array2 -Property WorkEmail -IncludeEqual -passthru | Where-Object {$_.SideIndicator -eq '=='})
```

That’s all fine and well.  When **WorkEmail** is equal in both *array1* and *array2*, I get the matching values from *array1* copied into *arrayNew*.  But is it possible to also include elements from *array2* in that copy process (basically taking elements from *array2* and adding them to *array1* when **WorkEmail** matches)?  I really only need to have **UserID** from *array2* included in *arrayNew* but if I can combine the two arrays (when there is a match) that would work for me also.  Can anything be done here – I haven’t been able to figure it out or find a solution?

(***Along with the original array values above, additional edits follow***):

Ideally, I'd like to end up with the following multi-dimensional array:

(arrayNew)

```
EmpID        Badge        WorkEmail          UserID
1234         ABCD         john@acme.com      1234
2345         JKLM         mary@acme.com      JKLM
4567         QWER         paul@acme.com      QWER
```

(Linda is skipped because there is no match for the **WorkEmail** element in both arrays)

(***Another edit below like @Cole9350 request - hopefully it helps and isn't too much***):

```
$ADobjects | Get-Member | fl
```

(mostly returns)

```
TypeName   : Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADObject
Name       : Contains
MemberType : Method
Definition : bool Contains(string propertyName)

TypeName   : Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADObject
Name       : Equals
MemberType : Method
Definition : bool Equals(System.Object obj)

TypeName   : Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADObject
Name       : GetEnumerator
MemberType : Method
Definition : System.Collections.IDictionaryEnumerator GetEnumerator()

TypeName   : Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADObject
Name       : GetHashCode
MemberType : Method
Definition : int GetHashCode()

TypeName   : Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADObject
Name       : GetType
MemberType : Method
Definition : type GetType()

TypeName   : Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADObject
Name       : ToString
MemberType : Method
Definition : string ToString()

TypeName   : Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADObject
Name       : SideIndicator
MemberType : NoteProperty
Definition : System.String SideIndicator===

TypeName   : Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADObject
Name       : Item
MemberType : ParameterizedProperty
Definition : Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection Item(string
         propertyName) {get;}

TypeName   : Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADObject
Name       : DistinguishedName
MemberType : Property
Definition : System.String DistinguishedName {get;set;}

TypeName   : Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADObject
Name       : Name
MemberType : Property
Definition : System.String Name {get;}

TypeName   : Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADObject
Name       : ObjectClass
MemberType : Property
Definition : System.String ObjectClass {get;set;}

TypeName   : Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADObject
Name       : ObjectGUID
MemberType : Property
Definition : System.Nullable`1[[System.Guid, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
         PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] ObjectGUID {get;set;}

TypeName   : Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADObject
Name       : userPrincipalName
MemberType : Property
Definition : System.String userPrincipalName {get;set;}
```

while

```
$CSVobjects | Get-Member | fl
```

(mostly returns)

```
TypeName   : System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
Name       : UserPrincipalName
MemberType : AliasProperty
Definition : UserPrincipalName = Work Email

TypeName   : System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
Name       : Equals
MemberType : Method
Definition : bool Equals(System.Object obj)

TypeName   : System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
Name       : GetHashCode
MemberType : Method
Definition : int GetHashCode()

TypeName   : System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
Name       : GetType
MemberType : Method
Definition : type GetType()

TypeName   : System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
Name       : ToString
MemberType : Method
Definition : string ToString()

TypeName   : System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
Name       : EmpID
MemberType : NoteProperty
Definition : System.String EmpID=1234

TypeName   : System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
Name       : Job Title
MemberType : NoteProperty
Definition : System.String Job Title =Genius

TypeName   : System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
Name       : Name
MemberType : NoteProperty
Definition : System.String Name=Coyote, Wile E

TypeName   : System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
Name       : SideIndicator
MemberType : NoteProperty
Definition : System.String SideIndicator==>

TypeName   : System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
Name       : Work Email
MemberType : NoteProperty
Definition : System.String Work Email=john.doe@acme.com
```

I was hoping that it would be simple so I originally kept the example simpler.  Now, minus a few elements, this is the heart of the arrays that I am really working with.  My goal, to compare the these two arrays based upon the **UserPrincipalName** member element (one is an alias) which will copy the items that are equal to a third array (leaving the original arrays untouched).  In addition to the matching items from the first array being copied to the new array, I also need to copy the member element **EmpID** from the 2nd array and add it to the newly created array as well (basically combining the arrays together).  Doesn't seem that COmpare-Object has that ability natively, so I've tried using things like Add-Member to do it.  But I do this:

```
$NewArray | Add-Member -membertype NoteProperty -Name 'EmpID' -Value 'tempdata'
```

I end up with the error:

```
Add-Member : Cannot add a member with the name "EmpID" because a member with that name already
exists. If you want to overwrite the member anyway, use the Force parameter to overwrite it.
(etc...)
```

Since I can't directly combine the data like I had wanted, my though was to add a new member to the new array (created by using **Compare-Object**) then **ForEach** through the original arrays to copy the additional data needed to the new array.

Thanks for any help

Comment: If you truly had an "array" or a "multidimensional array" it wouldn't look like a table. do `$array1 | get-member` to see what kind of object you are actually working with, or show us how you created that object

Comment: One array is from _Get-ADobject_ and the other is from _Import-CSV_.  They truly are multidimensional arrays.  In the current version of my script, I didn't actually create the array elements.  I tried to do that originally but had other problems, so I went with the easier _Import-CSV_ method.  Does that help?

Comment: Nope, that still doesn't make sense. The `Import-Csv` cmdlet returns a PSCustomObject. The `Get-ADobject` cmdlet returns an ActiveDirectory.Management.ADobject. An array, or arrays inside arrays, are something completely different

Comment: @Cole9350 - Is that what you are looking for?  Will that help?  Thanks

Comment: @Cole9350 - I think that I got it - if I add -Force to the Add-Member, it adds the element without the error messages.  Still testing...

Comment: Yes, I didn't mean to post the results, I was just trying to show you that the objects your referring to aren't arrays. I'm not gonna write the script for you tho. Your question has grown far too large, try simplifying down for better results. I can tell you that to solve this, I would use 2 loops: `$array1 | % {foreach($arr in $array2) { if ($_.WorkEmail -eq $arr.Email) { //add values to new custom object}}}`

Comment: @Cole9350 - Thanks.  I wasn't sure but figured the question would grow too large.  And you are right on the money on how I solved it, that was what I did and just got it worked out.  I was originally missing the -Force which pushed me away from the Add-Member with the error but once I added it, I was able to create the _ForEach_ loops and copy the data over.  I was originally hoping there was an easier way to do it using the _Compare-Object_ cmdlet directly, but I never found a way.  Multiple _ForEach_ loops seems to be the only way to do it.  Will post it shortly

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand the question. What's stopping you from simply adding them?

```
D:\> $arr1=@('a','b','c')
D:\> $arr2=@('d','e','c')
D:\> $arr1+$arr2
a
b
c
d
e
c
D:\> $arr1+$arr2 | select -unique
a
b
c
d
e
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I've updated the original post to better explain (and demonstrate the desired outcome) that I'm looking for.  Your suggestion will work for a simple array, but what I'm working with multi-dimensional arrays.  I only need to copy one element from an array to another array when there is a match with the **WorkEmail** element

Comment: You might then take a look at this blog post: http://www.happysysadm.com/2011/01/multidimensional-arrays-in-powershell.html You would make your life so much easier if you had chosen to create PSObjects instead of arrays though

Comment: Thanks.  I actually had used that method originally, but I ended up with different problems in the end.  What I'm doing it taking data from Active Directory and comparing it to data from an Excel report provided by a payroll vendor.  I used the example arrays above just to demonstrate what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: I think I understand what you are trying to do; I would just do it with objects; which are so much easier to manipulate (add remove columns, or properties) than figuring out a PowerShell multi-dimensional array. I never needed them, so sorry, can't help more.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I may end up going back and trying it the way I originally had it (with objects) if I can't figure it out, but then I'll have to figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up having to do was create the *$NewArray* first using custom objects:

```
[array]$NewArray = New-Object PSObject
Add-Member -InputObject $NewArray -membertype NoteProperty -Name 'CSVuserID' -Value ""
[array]$ NewArray = @()
```

I originally had to use the *–Force* option because I was creating the object inside the *ForEach* loop.  Now I am creating it before the *Get-ADobject* and before *Import-CSV* cmdlets run.  So now when I compare *$array1* and *$array2*, the *Compare-Object* cmdlet will automatically add any new member elements needed and (expand) the *$arrayNew* array.  I only need to create new objects for anything that I’m planning to copy between the arrays.

```
$arrayNew = @(Compare-Object $array1 $array2 -Property WorkEmail -IncludeEqual -passthru | Where-Object {$_.SideIndicator -eq '=='})
```

Then some *ForEach* loops and I end up with the desired output in *$NewArray*:

```
If ($arrayNew.Count -ge 1)
    {
    $arrayNew | ForEach-Object {
        ForEach ($obj in $array2) {
            If ($obj.Email.ToLower() -eq $_.Email.ToLower() -eq $True)
                {
                $_.CSVuserID = $obj.UserID
                Break
                }
            Else
                {
                Continue
                }
        }
    }
    }
```

Thanks for all the help